# Insert a new column to a list of dataframes by parsing the date names of the

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list of data frames which I would like to insert a new column into

```
df<- data_frame(first =seq(1:10), second = seq(1:10))
ldf <- list(df, df, df)
names(ldf) <- c('April 2018 ASP NDC-HCPCS Crosswalk', 'Apr 2019 ASP Pricing File', 'Jan 18 ASP Pricing File')
```

I wish to insert a new column into each data frame by taking the name of each data frame and converting it to the corresponding YYYY QQ format.

Using the example above, the April 2018 ASP NDC-HCPCS Crosswalk dataframe will have a new column called date which will contain "2018 Q2" for all 10 rows, similarly the Apr 2019 ASP Pricing File dataframe will have a new date column containing "2019 Q2" for all rows and finally the Jan 18 ASP Pricing File will have a new date column with "2018 Q1"

Comment: So there is no standard naming that the name follows? It could be `April`, `Apr`, `January`, `Jan` and same for years as well ?

Comment: You are actually asking two questions: 1) how to convert a string containing a date in a specific format, 2) how to create an id column while binding a list of `data.frame`s. These are different tasks and you should ask only one per question.

Comment: @RonakShah that's correct, for some files both the year and month are abbreviated and sometimes they're fully described eg December 2018

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of an approach you can use and improve on. You should probably make the regex more robust--although it works for your example I can see situations where it could fail. Also, this works for years 2000 and up; you would need to change it if you have any earlier dates. Let me know if you have any questions!

```
# Getting month indices
# Extracting month names
new_mon <- gsub(paste0(".*(", paste(c(month.name, month.abb), collapse = "|"), ").*"), "\\1", names(ldf))

# Subsetting a "quarter" vector by month name/abbreviation and taking nonmissing values
new_mon <- pmax(sort(rep(1:4, 3))[match(new_mon, month.name)],
                sort(rep(1:4, 3))[match(new_mon, month.abb)], na.rm = T)


# Getting the year indices and ading "20" if there are only two characters
new_year <- gsub(".*?([0-9]{2,4}).*", "\\1", names(ldf)) # This is good for your example but you can make it more robust
new_year <- ifelse(nchar(new_year) == 2, paste0("20", new_year), new_year)    



# Pasting them Together
new_cols <- paste0(new_year, " Q", new_mon)
```

**Results**:

```
# Adding the columns using Map
Map(function(x, y) cbind(x, "new_column" = y), ldf, new_cols)

$`April 2018 ASP NDC-HCPCS Crosswalk`
   first second new_column
1      1      1    2018 Q2
2      2      2    2018 Q2
3      3      3    2018 Q2
4      4      4    2018 Q2
5      5      5    2018 Q2
6      6      6    2018 Q2
7      7      7    2018 Q2
8      8      8    2018 Q2
9      9      9    2018 Q2
10    10     10    2018 Q2

$`Apr 2019 ASP Pricing File`
   first second new_column
1      1      1    2019 Q2
2      2      2    2019 Q2
3      3      3    2019 Q2
4      4      4    2019 Q2
5      5      5    2019 Q2
6      6      6    2019 Q2
7      7      7    2019 Q2
8      8      8    2019 Q2
9      9      9    2019 Q2
10    10     10    2019 Q2

$`Jan 18 ASP Pricing File`
   first second new_column
1      1      1    2018 Q1
2      2      2    2018 Q1
3      3      3    2018 Q1
4      4      4    2018 Q1
5      5      5    2018 Q1
6      6      6    2018 Q1
7      7      7    2018 Q1
8      8      8    2018 Q1
9      9      9    2018 Q1
10    10     10    2018 Q1
```

**Data**:

```
df<- data_frame(first =seq(1:10), second = seq(1:10))
ldf <- list(df, df, df)
names(ldf) <- c('April 2018 ASP NDC-HCPCS Crosswalk', 'Apr 2019 ASP Pricing File', 'Jan 18 ASP Pricing File')
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to start:

```
df<- data_frame(first =seq(1:10), second = seq(1:10))
ldf <- list(df, df, df)
names(ldf) <- c('April 2018 ASP NDC-HCPCS Crosswalk', 'Apr 2019 ASP Pricing File', 'Jan 18 ASP Pricing File')

lookup_quarters <- setNames(paste0("Q", rep(1:4, each = 3)),
                            c("jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun",
                              "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"))

lapply(seq_along(ldf), 
       function(i) {
         qtr <- substr(tolower(strsplit(names(ldf)[i], " ")[[1]][1]), 1, 3)
         qtr <- lookup_quarters[qtr]
         yr <- strsplit(names(ldf)[i], " ")[[1]][2]
         yr <- if (nchar(yr) == 2) paste0("20", yr) else yr
         res <- ldf[[i]]
         res$newcol <- paste(yr, qtr)
         res
       })
```